# vista con mas de 2 clases de modelo

Tags: mvc, razor

Hola estimados me pueden ayudar estoy creando un formulario en mvc y razor y estoy utilizando mas de una tabla por lo que requiero de diferentes clases de modelo en la vista sin embargo mvc no te permite mas que poner solo 1 me podrian ayudar por favor lo requiero ya que el formulario esta creado asi con varias tablas distintas .
estoy usando EF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Saludos.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!